# Marking or bookmarking questions as favorites for later access

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

I'm looking for something like a "Favorite Questions" on SO that would be accessible in my SO profile/account. This is not to be confused with the ability to tag one of your own questions as a favorite in your account, but rather have a simple mechanism where one can mark some of the great questions/answers posted on SO and add it to a list which could be accessed from their profile/account.

I couldn't find any existing question areas/help where one can request new features/enhancement. 
Do you have a feature that you would really love to see on SO?

Comment: Click the star next to the question. It shows up under the Favorites tab on your profile page.

Answer (score 3):

> **2** Click the star next to the question. It shows up under the Favorites tab on your profile page. – [Rex M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/67/rex-m) Jul 31 at 2:06

BTW I will NOT keep updating this to keep the time correct. I just won't do it.