# Is there a way to bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)
>   [Can I bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow)
>   [Stack Overflow Feature Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11330/stack-overflow-feature-request)

There's so much great content here, I'm wondering if there's a way to bookmark/favorite questions within SO?

Answer (score 5):

Click the star icon below the vote buttons.

You can see all of your bookmarked questions in your user page.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the star under the up/down vote.  Next time, questions like these go on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Click that little star icon on the left, beneath the rating.  FAVE'D!