# How to bookmark questions or answers I'm interested in?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to manage and keep track of answers and questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/any-way-to-manage-and-keep-track-of-answers-and-questions)

I am newbie on Stack Overflow.

When i find a good question or answer in Stack Overflow I'd like to save the link so that I can read it again later.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Questions about stackoverflow should be posted to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: See this other question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer

Comment: also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25756/is-there-a-way-to-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the star to mark it as a favorite.  Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser bookmarks!

Comment: thank you. but I'd like to find it again in my home too

Comment: Browser bookmark sync tools

Comment: There are bookmark synchroniser for major browsers. This can keep your browser bookmarks in sync at multiple locations. You can see XMarks for Firefox or IE

Comment: Or the built-in sync feature in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click on the star to put it in you stackoverflow favorites.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark questions "Favourite" in case you want to see them from your favourite tab in your user profile.